# Why use the method of images in magnetostatics?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics, method-of-images

If a current is above a conducting surface, why do we take the image of the current to find the magnetic field intensity? Why not just take the effect of the actual current only? And are this method and equations applied to satisfy boundary conditions at the surface?

Also, is there any good tutorial that explains the method of images in magnetostatics because I could not find any?

Comment: In slide 22 of this presentation(http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-007-electromagnetic-energy-from-motors-to-lasers-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_007S11_lec06.pdf) you can find a good tutorial. The method of image is used to ensure boundary conditions are met at boundary surface

Comment: ok but i got thus case but still not understanding the case when current in a medium with mu1 and the boundary surface is another medium mu2 the methods of image here is not clear why when calculating field in second medium we tale effect of current in medium 1 that is related in its value to actual current and mu1,mu2 why here there is no image current

Comment: The method of image is used when one of the mediums is a perfect electric conductor. The method is a trick to unsure that the boundary conditions at the interface between the two mediums is properly satisfied. In electrostatic case, if one of the mediums is a perfect electric conductor it doesn't make a difference what its epsilon is because conductivity overrides permitivity sort of say. I *would* assume the same is true for magnetostatics,you only use image method to study perfect conductor case which makes mu2 irrelevant @MaiFouad

Comment: but see the case that i mentioned in this reference page 280-282                                                                   http://books.google.com.eg/books?id=YiED1VQlaOUC&pg=PR2&lpg=PR2&dq=ELECTROMAGNETISM+:+Theory+and+Applications+By:+PRAMANIK,+ASHUTOSH&source=bl&ots=fd-KZoeyv7&sig=dEbeOpXD9maMhpz6NXVNM4IY-nw&hl=ar&sa=X&ei=6CaKUs2ON8WP7Ab6xoHgCw&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=snippet&q=methods%20of%20image&f=false

Comment: I see, but you are asking about a conducting surface, so the dielectric case is different from what you are asking about, right? @MaiFouad

Comment: ok i got it but in the case of perfect conductor why we assume that for static magnetic field normal component should be vanish as no field in the conductor from where we know that no magnetic field in the conductor

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11561/discussion-between-mai-fouad-and-gotaquestion)

Comment: as i found different explanation in kraus carver electromagnetics page 295 that assumed that motion of positive charge of actual current produce motion of image negative charge in the same direction so the direction of image current opposite to the actual current how this assumption satisfy the boundary condition

Comment: We can continue this in chat room @MaiFouad

Answer (score 1):

The current creates a magnetic field. The magnetic field has to satisfy the appropriate boundary conditions at the interface between the medium in which the current is flowing and the perfect conductor.

[The method of image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges) is a mathematical tool applied to ensure that the magnetic field at the interface between the two mediums satisfies the boundary conditions. It was originally developed to solve for electrostatic charges, then it was extended to magnetostatics and time varying magnetic fields. Have a look at chapter 4 of Pramanik book. Also, have a look at this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.165.5581&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for a review of method of image for electrostatic, magnetostatic and electromagnetic cases.